# How am i able to force an app to ask user camera permission?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I need to ask permission to allow Camera in an angular web application. When I switch the cameraId to start a new call (with the other camera) it works fine on Windows but on Andoroid i have this error:
Media acces NotReadableError: Could not start video source.
That seems due to camera permissions.

Thanks

```
  switchCamera() {
    for (let id of this.ids) {
      if (id != this.cameraId) {
        this.cameraId = id;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.dossierService.cameraId = this.cameraId;
    this.dossierService.fromClient = true;
    this.router.navigate(['videoperizia']);
  }
```

this method save the new Id of the camera inside this.dossierService.cameraId,
then I navigate to other components "videoperizia".
So if VideoPerizia has fromClient == true it navigate back to Client.component(this one in the code) and start a new call with the new ID:

```
        ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (this.dossierService.cameraId) {
      this.startCall(this.dossierService.cameraId);
    }
  }


startCall(cameraId?: string) {
        try {
          this.agoraService.client.getCameras(_ => {
            if (_.length > 1) {
              this.enableSwitchCamera = true   
              this.cameraId = cameraId || _[1].deviceId;
              this.ids = _.map(device => device.deviceId);
            }
            else {
              this.enableSwitchCamera = false;
              this.cameraId = _[0].deviceId;
            }
        this.joinClient();
      })
    } catch (error) {
      this.toastr.error("errore nell'acquisizione video")
    }
  }
```

join client:

```
 joinClient() {

        this.agoraService.client.join(null, this.dossierId, null, (uid) => {
          this.streamSpec = { streamID: uid, audio: true, cameraId: this.cameraId, microphoneId: null, video: true, screen: false }
          this.localStream = this.agoraService.createStream(this.streamSpec);
          this.localStream.setVideoProfile('720p_3');
          this.subscribeToStreams();
          this.callIsStarted = true;
        });
      }
```

when i start the call from the begin it works fine also on Android, but when i switch it works just on Windows and MacOs

obiviously when i navigate to "videoperizia" my component will go through ngOnDestroy:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.localStream) {
      this.localStream.stop();
      this.agoraService.client.unpublish(this.localStream);
    }    
    this.agoraService.client.leave();
  }
```

html :

```
<div id="agora_local_client" [style.height.px]="screenHeight" [style.width.px]="screenWidth" #clientVideo>  
</div>
```

then @ViewChild inside ts:

```
 @ViewChild("clientVideo") clientVideo
```

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm assuming that your using `<video>` tag, the trick here is to use HTML local alias (#) on `<video>` tag and access it inside `app.component.ts `using `@ViewChild()` decorator.

Comment: I have this tag: <div id="agora_local_client" [style.height.px]="screenHeight" [style.width.px]="screenWidth">
  
</div> 0where inside is wrapped a tag <video>
so when i refers the vide with # and the using @ViewChild() inside the .ts file how can i ask permission? thanks a lot

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I faced a similar issue before, if you testing on mobile with your local URL, then Chrome in Mobile blocks accessing of camera from http protocol. Try with Firefox.

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya, on mobile phone I'm using https protocol

Comment: Ok. Check if any other instance of browser is using the camera which is blocking it. I'm suspecting its not a permission issue as browser will ask for permission.

Comment: it ask the permission first time i start the call and it works on android too, it doesn't work when i switch the camera